# Error with Parent as Required Field when Uploading Attachment from Form

Tags: case, attachment

I am making a custom form with the standard Case controller that needs to be able to accept attachments. I have written a controller extension that does a couple of things, including handle the attachment. The problem I am running into is when i go to insert the attachment. The error states: *"Insert Failed REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Parent]: [Parent]"*.

I have, however, set the parentId for this attachment when I write: ParentId = supportCase.Id. Below is teh code for the controller extension:

```
public class PartnerSupportCaseController {

public Case supportCase {get;set;}

public Attachment attachedFile;



public PartnerSupportCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

    this.supportCase = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    supportCase.Protocol_Sub_Issue__c = 'Partner Support - Please Pick';
    supportCase.Protocol_Issue__c = 'Partner Support - Please Pick';
    supportCase.RecordTypeId = '012M000000092ju';


}

public Attachment getAttachedFile(){
    attachedFile = New Attachment();
    return attachedFile;

}



public pagereference Save()
{


    Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = supportCase.Id, name = attachedFile.Name, body = attachedFile.Body);

    insert supportCase;
    insert a;      

    PageReference pg = Page.PartnerSupportThankYou;
    pg.setredirect(true);
    return pg;


  }


 }
```

I am also adding the excerpt from my form where the file is taken in:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Case" extensions="PartnerSupportCaseController">

<apex:pageBlockSection>

           <apex:inputfile value="{!attachedFile.body}" filename="{!attachedFile.Name}" />                       
           </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I just need to pinpoint why this insert is failing due to a missing required field, even though I have filled that required field.

Thanks,
-CP

Comment: are you passing case id in url ?

Comment: In the form URL? I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting this as answer because if I put that as comment you might confuse with syntax.

you have defined a visualforce page and until and unless you are not passing id of case in url controller will not get it, Try to get one case id in your org and pass this in url in following way.

```
/apex/YOURVFPAGENAME?id=CASERECORDID
```

replace both parameters.

1. YOURVFPAGENAME with your visualforce page name
2. CASERECORDID with any case id.

if you want to create a case everytime you upload attachment update your save method in following way

```
public pagereference Save()
{

   upsert supportCase;
   Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = supportCase.Id, name = attachedFile.Name, body = attachedFile.Body);
   insert a; 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that now. Do you mean, in this instance, substituting CASERECORDID with supportCase.Id? This needs to create a case every time as opposed to update one.

Comment: are you creating case everytime you add attachment ?

Comment: no, every time this form is filled out, and then redirected to the "thank you" page, a new case should be created. Attachments will only sometimes be included (as attachments is an optional field on the form)

Comment: this error was coming because you were referring the supportcase.id prior to inserting the case record which you were creating support case. which was making supportcase.id in Attaachment a line.

Comment: Ah ok. would I need to write code to index it or move that bit to after "insert supportCase;?

Comment: I have updated my answer please check that. :)

Comment: Magical. I have marked this as the answer. Many thanks.

Comment: welcome Chris :)